# Spark: Convert column of string to an array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

How to convert a column that has been read as a string into a column of arrays?
i.e. convert from below schema

```
scala> test.printSchema
root
 |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |-- b: string (nullable = true)

+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|2,3|
+---+---+
|  2|4,5|
+---+---+
```

To:

```
scala> test1.printSchema
root
 |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |-- b: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)

+---+-----+
|  a|  b  |
+---+-----+
|  1|[2,3]|
+---+-----+
|  2|[4,5]|
+---+-----+
```

Please share both scala and python implementation if possible. 
On a related note, how do I take care of it while reading from the file itself?
I have data with ~450 columns and few of them I want to specify in this format.
Currently I am reading in pyspark as below:

```
df = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(
    header='true', inferschema='true', delimiter='|').load(input_file)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are various method,

The best way to do is using `split` function and cast to `array<long>`

```
data.withColumn("b", split(col("b"), ",").cast("array<long>"))
```

You can also create simple udf to convert the values

```
val tolong = udf((value : String) => value.split(",").map(_.toLong))

data.withColumn("newB", tolong(data("b"))).show
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Would anyone have an example of doing the reverse of this converting an array of strings to tab separated column?

Comment: What if, the above 2,3 is a tuple (2,3) and then need to create an array @thebluephantom @ koiralo

Comment: What do you mean by tuple? Can you share the schema? You could youse  `array()` function to create a list from columns.

Answer (score 3):

In python (pyspark) it would be:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, split
test = test.withColumn(
        "b",
        split(col("b"), ",\s*").cast("array<int>").alias("ev")
 )
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a [UDF](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-sql-udfs.html) would give you exact required schema. Like this:

```
val toArray = udf((b: String) => b.split(",").map(_.toLong))

val test1 = test.withColumn("b", toArray(col("b")))
```

It would give you schema as follows:

```
scala> test1.printSchema
root
 |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |-- b: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)

+---+-----+
|  a|  b  |
+---+-----+
|  1|[2,3]|
+---+-----+
|  2|[4,5]|
+---+-----+
```

As far as applying schema on file read itself is concerned, I think that is a tough task. So, for now you can apply transformation after creating `DataFrameReader` of `test`.

I hope this helps!