# Load CSV data in to Dataframe and convert to Array using Apache Spark (Java)

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-dataset

I have a CSV file with below data :

```
1,2,5  
2,4  
2,3
```

I want to load them into a Dataframe having schema of string of array

The output should be like below.

```
[1, 2, 5]  
[2, 4]  
[2, 3]
```

This has been answered using scala here:
[Spark: Convert column of string to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44690174/spark-convert-column-of-string-to-an-array)

I want to make it happen in Java.
Please help

Comment: The question you have attached uses DSL. It'll be almost similar in Java as well. Did you try writing anything? If yes, what error did you get?

Comment: I was trying to load it a RDD and attach schema to it as below : 
 JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = sparkSession.read().textFile("D:\\sanjaya\\OAWorkspace\\spark-basics\\src\\main\\resources\\marketbasketdata.csv")
    .javaRDD().map((Function<String, Row>) record -> {
     String[] attributes = record.split(",");
     return RowFactory.create(Arrays.asList(attributes));   <br>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the sample code in Java. You need to read your file using `spark.read().text(String path)` method and then call the `split` function.

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.split;

public class SparkSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("SparkSample")
                .master("local[*]")
                .getOrCreate();
        //Read file
        Dataset<Row> ds = spark.read().text("c://tmp//sample.csv").toDF("value");
        ds.show(false);     
        Dataset<Row> ds1 = ds.select(split(ds.col("value"), ",")).toDF("new_value");
        ds1.show(false);
        ds1.printSchema();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use VectorAssembler class to create as array of features, which is particulary useful with pipelines:

```
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("city", "status", "vendor"))
  .setOutputCol("features")
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html#vectorassembler